# Linearize a BOM, issue when using setValues(result) instead of appendRow

Tags: google-apps-script

Input is as follows (this is a simplified example)

| LEVEL | NAME | JOB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Alpha |
| 2 | B | Bravo |
| 3 | C | Charlie |
| 4 | D | Delta |
| 2 | E | Echo |
| 3 | F | Foxtrot |
| 2 | G | Golf |
| 2 | H | Hotel |
| 3 | I | India |
| 4 | J | Juliet |

I have to linearize to obtain that output

| NAME level 1 | JOB level 1 | NAME level 2 | JOB level 2 | NAME level 3 | JOB level 3 | NAME level 4 | JOB level 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Alpha | B | Bravo | C | Charlie | D | Delta |
| A | Alpha | E | Echo | F | Foxtrot |  |  |
| A | Alpha | G | Golf |  |  |  |  |
| A | Alpha | H | Hotel | I | India | J | Juliet |

I achive that by using a temporary array (temp) and appendRow, which is a bit slow. When I manage to use a big array (result) and setValues(result), I only get the last row

| NAME level 1 | JOB level 1 | NAME level 2 | JOB level 2 | NAME level 3 | JOB level 3 | NAME level 4 | JOB level 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Alpha | H | Hotel | I | India | J | Juliet |
| A | Alpha | H | Hotel | I | India | J | Juliet |
| A | Alpha | H | Hotel | I | India | J | Juliet |
| A | Alpha | H | Hotel | I | India | J | Juliet |

I can't understand what is wrong in my script ! Any help to understand will be usefull.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zoT9kk-Am_yUOLCAAvccJOTH0UZ7lrRiLYpPtqb9RXY/copy

```
function linearize() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Original')
  const data = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()
  const nbData = sh.getLastColumn() - 1

  const bd1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('BD1') // for test with appendrow
  const bd2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('BD2') // for test with result
  bd1.clearContents()
  bd2.clearContents()

  let result = []
  let levelMax = 0
  let headers = []
  data.forEach(r => levelMax = Math.max(levelMax, r[0]))
  for (let i = 1; i <= levelMax; i++) {
    headers.push(['NAME level ' + i, 'JOB level ' + i])
  }
  bd1.appendRow(headers.flat())
  result.push(headers.flat())
  // everything ok until this step ==============
  let temp = []
  data.forEach(function (r, i) {
    // save values
    var level = r[0]
    for (let x = 0; x < nbData; x++) {
      temp[nbData * (level - 1) + x] = r[x + 1]
    }
    // blank values from level+1 to levelMax
    if (level < levelMax) {
      for (let y = (level * 1 + 1); y <= levelMax; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < nbData; x++) {
          temp[nbData * (y - 1) + x] = ''
        }
      }
    }
    // output when the following level will not increase or at the final row
    if (i < data.length - 1) {
      if (data[i + 1][0] <= data[i][0]) {
        bd1.appendRow(temp)
        result.push(temp)
      }
    }
    else {
      bd1.appendRow(temp)
      result.push(temp)
    }

  })
  bd2.getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- By modifying your script, you want to achieve the situation of `I have to linearize to obtain that output` using `bd2.getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result)`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (i < data.length - 1) {
  if (data[i + 1][0] <= data[i][0]) {
    bd1.appendRow(temp)
    result.push(temp)
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
if (i < data.length - 1) {
  if (data[i + 1][0] <= data[i][0]) {
    bd1.appendRow(temp);
    result.push([...temp]); // <--- Modified. Or result.push(temp.slice())
  }
}
```

- I thought that in your script, `temp` is used as the pass-by-reference. By this, the issue of `I only get the last row` occurs. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. So, in this case, `temp` is copied with `[...temp]` and/or `temp.slice()`. By this, it becomes the pass-by-value.